# How to create author dropdown having list of authors in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How to create authors list dropdown in wordpress ?
I need to filter posts by author.

Please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo '<form method="get">';
$authors = get_users( 'orderby=nicename' );
$ret='';
foreach ( $authors as $aut ) {
    $ret.= '<option value="'.$aut->ID.'">' . esc_html( $aut->user_nicename ) . '</option>';
}
echo '<select name="author">'.$ret.'</select><input type="submit"></form>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
<ul>
  <?php $allUsers = get_users('show_fullname=1&optioncount=1&orderby=post_count&order=DESC&role=author');
        foreach($allUsers as $user){ ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $user->display_name; echo " (".count_user_posts( $user->ID ).")";?></a></li>

  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```